# .Net remoting works from example but not from my assembly

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, socketexception

I have downloaded a simple .Net remoting example from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8771/Simple-but-potentially-useful-example-of-NET-Remot . The example works. The server side code is called by the client. Now when I copy that client code into my own C# project like the code below, it gives me a SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

**EDIT 1 START**

Its even getting stranger. When I have a test project as a client that works, and I add that working project to the solution I am working on, and run a new debug instance of the project (it is the only project ran from the solution on that moment), it gives me the SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
It looks like it has something to do with a solution based configuration or so.

**END 1 END**

Because of this strange behavior I wanted to see if I was missing something. So I created a new (winforms) project in a new solution and I put the exact same code in the new form1_load event. And it works, the server side code is called by this newly created winforms application. How is it possible that one application can connect over remoting to execute server side code, and another application can't, by using the exact same code?
And yes, I turned Windows Firewall off, and I do not have any other firewall.

And all of the above is tested on one computer. So there is no physical network involved.

Any suggestions?

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        TcpClientChannel channel = new TcpClientChannel();
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel);
        IProcessActivator.IProcessActivator process_activator = (IProcessActivator.IProcessActivator)Activator.GetObject
        (
            typeof(IProcessActivator.IProcessActivator),
            "tcp://localhost:9000/ProcessActivator"
        );
        process_activator.Run("IExplore.exe", @"http://www.codeproject.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go and check whether the remoting service is running on port `9000`. This usually happens on our side due to the fact that the port on which the server is listening is not the port you're trying to connect from the client. Also there can be firewall issues, So make sure that the port `9000` is added as an exception in the firewall.

Comment: The remoting service is running on the right port as a client in Solutation A can connect, but a client with the exact same code in Solution B can not. Firewall is turned off, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

On server side, your downloaded code is running on port 9000 for TCP channel and on port 8000 for HttpChannel. Check whether you set both the port to 9000 in your code? Use only one port for one communication channel. If you application crashed some times then your server side code is running in background. please close the process them.

Second reason, May be in your project there is another project which also used the same port for communication.So When your server is going to run , it stops to listen on that port and through the target invocation exception with Socket.

Comment: I am not using HttpChannel. And the code in Solution A and B are exactly the same. But solution A can connect but solution B can not.